# How to validate that a string from a textbox contains only 2 characters and 3 numbers?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web

I have checked other answers and am not finding what I need to know. I have a variable named nationalID which can only contain 2 characters and 3 numbers (ex. aa123) How do I say this in java? I am using Netbeans and have looked at all of the methods that pops up but I am not seeing anything that will help me. This is what I have so far.

```
private String validator(String nationalID, String lastName, String firstName, String dateOfBirth) {
    // nationalID should have 2 characters and 3 digits ex. AB123
    // dateOfBirth should be yyyy-mm-dd

    if(nationalID.length() != 5 || nationalID.){
        String err;
        return err =  "Your National ID has to be 5 characters long";
    }

    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method of String with regex like:

```
 if(nationalID.matches("[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{3}")) {
     System.out.println("Yes it does contains pattern");
 }
```

[A-Za-z]{2} Means be it any two known character either between A-Z or a-z.
[0-9]{3} Means be it any combination of numbers between 0-9 repeated thrice which follows two known characters.

Comment: How do i check to see if nationalID does not match that format?

Comment: just add "!" before the method call like `if(!nationalID.matches("[A-Za-z]{2}[0-9]{3}")) {`